# Reinitialise a class when its method has been called N times

Tags: python

I'm working on a web scraper, built on Selenium, that looks something like this:

```
class Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),   
        )
        return self

    def extract(self):
        # does some extraction and transformation
        return

    def etl(self):
        self.driver.get(url)
        # some other stuff

    def __exit__(self):
        self.driver.close()
```

From another file I initialise this class with a `with` block and call the `etl` method in a `while True` loop like so:

```
with Scraper() as scraper:
    while True:
        scraper.etl() 
        # keep iterating
```

However, my memory fills up after a couple hundred calls and I have to reinitialise `webdriver.Chrome` to free up memory. Can I simply count the times `etl` has been called and call `Scraper.__enter__()`? Or is there a smarter pattern to use here?

Comment: Why can't you just initialize `self.driver` in `__init__` and re-use it instead of creating a new driver whenever `__enter__` is called?

Comment: And ditch the `__enter__` and the `with` block all together? So basically initialising the class with every iter in the `while True` loop?

Comment: No, you can still have `def __enter__(self): return self` (or `return self.driver` so it can be used directly from the `with` block)

Comment: @DeepSpace I don't think there is anything wrong with re-initializing the driver in `__enter__`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga was doing that while you were typing out that comment lol

Comment: "Can I simply count the times etl has been called and call Scraper.__enter__()? Or is there a smarter pattern to use here" The more reasonable thing would be to do something like `while True: with Scraper() as scraper: for _ in range(N): scraper.etl()` So each iteration of the`while` loop creates a scraper instance, and you use a nested `for` loop to call `scraper.etl()` some `N` number of times.

Comment: It's actually not returning self but didn't want to leave it empty.

Comment: Fair point, changed it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution to this would be to do something like:

```
N = 100 # or however many times you want

while True:
    with Scraper() as scraper:
        for _ in range(N):
            scraper.elt()
```

Or, re-organize your class, something like:

```
class Scraper:
    ...
    def init_driver(self):
        # perhaps you have to handle closing an already opened driver... 
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),   
        )
    def __enter__(self):
        self.init_driver()
        return self
```

Then:

```
N = 100
with Scraper() as scraper:
    while True:
         for _ in range(N):
             scraper.etl()
         scraper.init_driver()
```

Although, the first option seems more clean to me.

Comment: This doesn't run forever though. The goal is to call `scraper.etl` forever, while reinitialising `webdriver.Chrome` in `__enter__` every `N` iterations. Apologies if that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: @DSteman this *does* run forever, where do you think it will terminate? It's an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah you're absolutely right, my bad. Another error got raised because __exit__() was receiving more arguments than expected so I thought the range generator was empty and the loop was broken, but not the case.